# Dativ oder Akkusativ bei 'schreiben/lesen in'

Tags: dative, accusative

Welche von den folgenden Sätzen sind falsch und warum?

> Ich schreibe einen Brief.
>
> Ich habe einen Brief geschrieben.

Jetzt mit in:

> Ich habe in den Brief über meine Probleme geschrieben.
>
> Ich schrieb in den Brief über meine Probleme.

lesen:

> Ich lese das Buch.
>
> Ich habe das Buch gelesen.

Jetzt mit in:

> Ich habe in das Buch gelesen.
>
> Ich habe in das Buch viele Beispiele gelesen.

Kurzgefragt:
schreiben in (Dativ oder Akkusativ)

lesen in (Dativ oder Akkusativ)

Comment: You cannot say ins Buch but you can say im Buch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lesen**

The correct form for reading is in most cases:

> Ich habe in dem Buch (Dat) gelesen.
>
> I read in the book.
>
> Ich habe in dem Buch (Dat) viele Beispiele (Akk) gelesen.
>
> I read many examples in the book.

You can use the accusative with a different verb (hineinlesen), but it changes the meaning from just reading to speculation, and needs a an additional accusative object to indicate what the result of that interpretation.

> Ich habe etwas (Akk) in das Buch (Akk) hineingelesen.
>
> I read something in the book and interpreted it in a certain way.

**Schreiben**

You always use accusative for both what you write and where you write it.

> Ich habe meine Probleme (Akk) in den Brief (Akk) geschrieben.

But if you combine this with "über", it changes:

> Ich habe über meine Probleme (Akk) in dem Brief (Dat) geschrieben.

which I'd normally change to

> Ich habe in dem Brief (Dat) über meine Probleme (Akk) geschrieben.

because it sounds more natural to me. The first form might also be misunderstood as if you were writing (somewhere, not specified) about any problems (maybe delivery? maybe writing?) you had with the letter. You'd probably better use "Probleme mit dem Brief" if you actually mean the later, though.

You also use dative to indicate e.g., the means of writing:

> Ich habe mit dem Bleistift (Dat) geschrieben.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be always dative in your examples, because reading and writing is not a movement in German.

```
EDIT: in your second and fourth examples, of course.
```

There is an exception, however: If you want to focus on the action of writing into something rather than anything else, you can use the accusative.

> Ich habe in das Heft geschrieben. Nicht in das Buch.

Comment: Falsch! Ich habe meine Probleme in den Brief geschrieben.

Comment: That's the same exception. You focus on the action of **writing into the letter** rather than *writing on the blackboard* for example. Word order is important, as is the ommision of "über" in your latest example. You first examples *Ich habe in den Brief über meine Probleme geschrieben.* and *Ich schrieb in den Brief über meine Probleme.* both focus on *meine Probleme* instead, because of *über* and the position in sentence. Because of that, both should be in dative and use **in dem** instead of **in den**.

Comment: And addition: **über** is important because it declares the topic of a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Ob *lesen in* und *schreiben in* mit Dativ oder Akkusativ stehen kommt darauf an, welche Aussage getroffen werden soll. Der Kontext bestimmt den Fall. Wenn Du mit *in* den Ort angibst, an dem/in den Du etwas schreibst, steht das mit Dativ:

> Ich schreibe im/in dem Zug (wo)
>   Ich schreibe im/in dem Heft (wo) und nicht im Buch

Wenn Du mit *in* angibst **wohin** Du etwas schreibst, dann steht das mit Akkusativ:

> Ich schreibe in das Heft (wohin)

Ähnlich verhält es sich mit *lesen*. Wenn Du angibst, wen oder was Du liest, dann steht das mit Akkusativ:

> Ich lese das Buch (was, Akk.)
>   Ich lese die Inschrift (wen, Akk.)

Wenn Du allerdings angibst, wo Du etwas liest, dann steht das mit Dativ:

> Ich lese im/in dem Zug (wo, Dat.) ein Buch (was, Akk.)
>   Ich lese im/in dem Buch (wo, Dat.) einen Satz (was, Akk.)

Comment: Ich kann trotzdem den Unterschied nicht verstehen zwischen Wo und Wohin in deinen Beispielen:
Ich schreibe in dem Heft (wo).
Ich schreibe in das Heft (wohin).

Comment: Das ist richtig. Aber das eine steht eben mit Akkusativ und das andere mit Dativ. Daher kannst Du eben nicht sagen: *Ich habe in das Buch gelesen*.